# How should we use google analytic script in django?

Tags: html, django, google-analytics

Can we add google analytic script in  tag and push it to the GitHub or we should keep it secret i.e. add it to the .env file and call in .

When I tried by the second one it appears in the source page as it is and also not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there is no meaning of hiding it because it is also shown when 'view page source' is clicked. All you need is a simple filter. It will only include traffic on your domain, protecting yourself from any data corruption when people hijack your Google Analytics Property ID.

To find your filters:

- Go to your Google Analytics standard reports
- Click on the “Admin” button in the top right
- Click on “Filters”
- Click “+ New Filter

Then use these settings for your filter:

- Select “Create New filter for Profile”
- Name your filter with something snazzy like “Hacking Defense”
- Select “Custom Filter”
- Select “Include”
- For the Filter Field, select “Hostname”
- If your site is LarsLofgren.com, you would define the filter pattern
  as “larslofgren.com” and make sure to include a “\” before any “.”
- Pick “No” for case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, your analytics id will be visible on your website. So, I don't think you should make an effort to hide it.

Just add it to your base template and you should be ready to go :)